How/Why can pip install CUDA drivers?
Nowadays, installing pytorch or tensorflow with pip also installs CUDA drivers, see e.g. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
Since when / how is that possible? My understanding for a long time was that pip could only install python packages and that one of the most important benefits of conda was that it could also install other stuff.

It can't. You are mistaken

There are various aspects to a full CUDA install.  Sometimes "CUDA drivers" is used to refer to something different than "GPU driver".  pip is not installing the GPU driver, but it can install something called a CUDA driver.

With pip you can install anything that was packed as a Python wheel. For example you can install Cmake with pip install cmake; it will be installed from https://pypi.org/project/cmake/#files where it has been packaged.
pip install tensorflow[and-cuda] installs CUDA drivers packaged as wheels: https://pypi.org/project/nvidia-cublas-cu12/ , https://pypi.org/project/nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12/ and so on…

Those wheels are not OS drivers, they are runtime libraries. Not the same thing

@talonmies Sure. But the question is a bit vague, I don't fully understand what are "CUDA drivers" the OP asked so I decided to read it in a more extended sense.

Thanks for the answer @phd! And yes, I meant the CUDA libraries not the NVidia drivers, sorry.
Out of curiosity: I think packaged CUDA libraries were not available (or at least not in mainstream use) for several years. I remember several instructions where you had to install them yourself or use e.g. conda. Why the change?

@gebbissimo No idea, I don't use CUDA or Tensorflow. Wild guess — they just want to make it simpler for the users. https://pypi.org/project/nvidia-cublas-cu12/#history I see they started to release wheels at the end of 2022 https://pypi.org/project/nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12/#history
